# An exe changes CMD font

Tags: cmd, windows-10, litedb

I have custom fonts for CMD. When I run LiteDB Shell it changes my font even after I leave the shell. How do I stop this from happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no font change. The characters of green prompt before execution of `LiteDB.Shell.exe` look identical to the characters of the gray prompt after shell closed.

The text color has changed, but that can be easily changed back with command **color**. Run in a command prompt window `color /?` for help on this command.

Run `color 0A` to get back green text on black background. Or run just `color` without a parameter to restore the background and foreground color on start of command process `cmd.exe` as explained by the help.